# How to Fill a Form with Data from a JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html

I have two file, a JSON storing some data and a simple html form.

I want to fill the form with random data taken from a JSON. Those data should be relative to the same object.

My form looks like:

```
<form id="first_form">
  Name:<br>
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  Phone:<br>
  <input id="phone" type="number" name="phone">
  <br>
  City:<br>
  <input id="city" type="text" name="city">
  <br>
  Pcode:<br>
  <input id="pcode" type="number" name="pcode">
  Note:<br>
  <input id="note" type="text" name="note">
  <br>
</form>
```

My JSON looks like:

```
users: [
 {
   "name": "name1",
   "phone": "111111111",
   "address": "address1",
   "city": "city1",
   "pcap": 1111,
   "note": ""
 },
 {
   "name": "name2",
   "phone": "222222222",
   "address": "address2",
   "city": "city2",
   "pcap": 2222,
   "note": ""
 },
 {
   "name": "name3",
   "phone": "333333333",
   "address": "address3",
   "city": "city3",
   "pcap": 3333,
   "note": ""
 },
 {
   "name": "name4",
   "phone": "44444444",
   "address": "address4",
   "city": "city4",
   "pcap": 4444,
   "note": ""
 }
]
```

Is there a way to do so in a no-jQuery way?

Comment: What have you tried already? Beside that if it contains `users: {` then it is not JSON encoded data but a JavaScript Object. Because in a JSON formatted data, keys must have double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it is `users =` rather than `users :`. Also change id 'pcode' to 'pcap'

In that case you can use the following code

```
var indx = Math.floor(Math.random()*users.length);
var randUser = users[indx];

for(prop in randUser) {
  document.getElementById(prop).value = randUser[prop];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that work! 

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/hkj9nvhf/

Last question, is it possible to do so if the json is an external file? thank you again

Comment: Yes it is. You can load JSON via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

There are non-jquery (or other framework) ways to do this, but they are quite tedious (thats why these frameworks exists).

In addition: How would your fill a "single" form with an ARRAY of objects? you will either need to repeat the form or have some way of selecting which dataset you want.

One easy way to fill a form from a json is https://github.com/corinis/jsForm
(disclaimer: I am the author of that module)

---

If you really want to do it the hard way I suggest taking a close look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

You need to start processing the complete DOM and identify which form-fields match input and have to worry about the cross-browser dom implementation issues.

Basically you start with getting the "root" of where you want to start parsing:

```
var root = document.getElementById("first_form");
```

and then have a recursive function that goes through all children and its childrent to identify a form, which you can then check against your object:.

```
function replace(root, obj) {
  var children = root.childNodes;
  for(var i = 0; i < children.lenght; i++) {
     var child = children[i];
     // go deep
     if(child.children) {
         replace(child, obj);
     } 
     // check if we have a name attribute - then assume its a form and set its value
     if(child.getAttribute("name")) {
         child.setAttribute("value", obj[child.getAttribute("name")]);
     }
  }
}
```

You can extend the code to also allow sub-objects or other peculiarities in your object.

Going the other way round (doing a for-in in your object and searching for fields) also works and is less code, but that only works for very simple objects.

Comment: The OP says `Is there a way to do so in a no-jQuery way?`, but you link to a jQuery library.

Comment: Thank you for your replys. What I want is to randomly choose an object from the array and use the data to compile the form